# Are these two set notations equivalent for Cartesian Power

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

$A^k =$ {$(a_1, a_2, ... , a_k): a_1, a_2, ... , a_k \in A$}

and

$A^k =$ {$(a_1, a_2, ... , a_k) \in A$}

Is the second one just a short notation for saying the set of all tuples of length "k" that are made up of elements in A with replacement, but order matters?

Thanks!

Comment: Shorthand notations are always abuses of notation.  If in context there is no chance of confusion, you can consider using it, but this still doesn't mean it's a good idea.

Comment: In this particular case, no, the second version is ambiguous and just bad.

Answer (score 0):

No.  Your second line picks the elements of $A$ that are ordered lists of length $k$.  If $A$ contains many elements, but none that are ordered lists of length $k$, then the set you have written is empty (and it should not be).

Comment: To make the 2nd one equivalent I would have to say then "for a_i in A, where 1 <= i <= k" correct?

Comment: The question asked whether the second notation is a *shorthand* for the first, and it definitely is - it's used frequently in logic.

Comment: @NoahSchweber : [citation needed].